# Making SVG responsive

Tags: css, svg

I have an SVG with the following code. I'd like to make it have a responsive width, and I've read that you shouldn't set width and height on the viewport, but when I remove them the SVG disappears. How should I change this so that the SVG will resize?

```css
.thumb_arrow{
  z-index: 1000;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  float: right;
  position:relative;
  bottom: 2rem;
  left:2rem;
  margin-right:1rem;
  @media (min-width: @screen-medium) {
    margin-right: 15rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="10em" height="10em"viewBox="0 0 50 100" enable-background="new 0 0 73.672 275.734" xml:space="preserve"> 
  <path fill="#ABABAB" d="M59.717,50.177c0-13.252-3.631-25.945-10.495-36.82l2.998-1.873L39.891,0.667l4.318,15.823l3.1-1.937 c6.64,10.515,10.152,22.797,10.152,35.624c0,12.927-3.56,25.284-10.294,35.848l-2.959-1.849L39.891,100L52.22,89.183l-3.14-1.962 C56.037,76.298,59.717,63.529,59.717,50.177z"/> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/30717551/104380

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try adding a container element with a defined width around your SVG, then removing width and height. It should fill the space.

You also need to increase the width of the viewBox to accommodate the whole shape.

```css
.svg-container {
 width: 300px;
 height: 150px;
 resize: both;
 overflow: auto;
 border: 1px dashed #aaa;
}

svg {
 width: 95%;
 height: 95%;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 60 100"> 
    <path fill="#ABABAB" d="M59.717,50.177c0-13.252-3.631-25.945-10.495-36.82l2.998-1.873L39.891,0.667l4.318,15.823l3.1-1.937 c6.64,10.515,10.152,22.797,10.152,35.624c0,12.927-3.56,25.284-10.294,35.848l-2.959-1.849L39.891,100L52.22,89.183l-3.14-1.962 C56.037,76.298,59.717,63.529,59.717,50.177z"/> 
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set the max-with to 100% i.e

```css
svg {
  max-width: 100%
}
```

This means, the image will always adapt to the width of its container

Comment: For those who work with Bootstrap (v5, Nov 2021): you can add `.mw-100` to the `<svg>` element which has this effect.

Answer (score 3):

Just provide `height` and `width` to `svg` tag.

```
svg {
      width:  auto;
      height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For me I had to make the circle responsive instead of path, This is how I did that.

```
.circle-container {
  width: 6vw;
  height: 6vw;
}

<div class='circle-container'>
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <circle cx="46" cy="45" r="40"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```

P.S - Circle **r, cx, cy** might be different for you, but the context set the width and height attributes of the SVG to **"100%"**, viewBox.

Answer (score 0):

⚠️ Something changed in the `contentBoxSize` object in newer browsers versions, those demos weren't working while they was before. It's fixed here, see edit to support older browsers.

---

Svg is powerful. It's **all about the viewBox.**, using *JavaScript* to control the `viewBox` allows to create amazing impossible stuffs.

Here is a way to **reset the viewBox** to the parent container dimensions, on dimensions change.

Using the *javascript* [resize Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Resize_Observer_API).

```js
function resetViewbox(e){
   box.setAttribute("viewBox","0 0 "+e[0].contentBoxSize[0].inlineSize+" "+e[0].contentBoxSize[0].blockSize)      
   //console.log("New viewBox: ", box.getAttribute("viewBox"))   
}

new ResizeObserver(resetViewbox).observe(fluid)
```

```css
#fluid {
  width: 200px;
  height:100px;
  overflow: auto;
  resize: both;
  border: 3px black solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 8vh
}
```

```html
<div id="fluid">
   <svg id="box" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
   <circle cx="76" cy="56" r="30" fill="blue"/>
   <text  x="10" y="30">I stay readable!</text>
   </svg>
</div>
```

This can be used in a lot of different ways:

```js
function resetViewbox(e){
   //console.log(e[0].contentBoxSize[0].blockSize)
   text.setAttribute("y", e[0].contentBoxSize[0].blockSize / 4)
}

new ResizeObserver(resetViewbox).observe(fluid)
```

```css
#fluid {
  width: 280px;
  height:100px;
  overflow: auto;
  resize: both;
  border: 3px black solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2rem
}
```

```html
<div id="fluid">
   <svg id="box" viewBox="0 0 280 100">
   <circle cx="76" cy="56" r="30" fill="blue"/>
   <text id="text" x="10" y="30">I stay readable!</text>
   </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap class `img-fluid` to make `svg` responsive.

```
<svg class="img-fluid" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="10em" height="10em"viewBox="0 0 50 100" enable-background="new 0 0 73.672 275.734" xml:space="preserve"> 
        <path fill="#ABABAB" d="M59.717,50.177c0-13.252-3.631-25.945-10.495-36.82l2.998-1.873L39.891,0.667l4.318,15.823l3.1-1.937 c6.64,10.515,10.152,22.797,10.152,35.624c0,12.927-3.56,25.284-10.294,35.848l-2.959-1.849L39.891,100L52.22,89.183l-3.14-1.962 C56.037,76.298,59.717,63.529,59.717,50.177z"/> 
</svg>
```