# how to make svg responsive

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive-design

I'm trying to make this massive svg responsive. However, it's not working and I don't know why.

I tried the following: - setting width: 100% height: auto (the diagram disappeared as soon as I removed the set width/height in pixel, regardless what i put back) - using the viewbox attribute as suggested by https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/

Here's the code (yes, I know it's huge.  why I need to make it fit to 100% width): http://www.cssdesk.com/bsakG

Can someone give me some hint as to what I'm doing wrong? I tried many things suggested by other articles, but I seem to keep running into the same problem where if I get rid of the fixed height/width, the whole thing disappeared.

(and yes I know this question may have been asked before, but none of the answers solved my problem)

Comment: Aren't SVG's already responsive? Isn't that the nature of an SVG (**Scale-able** Vector Graphics)?

Comment: Yes, it's scalable, so I'm asking how to scale it, because by default, numbers are given to each path.  Different sites suggested there are different ways to manipulate it through different attribute in the <svg> tag, but I haven't been successful.

Comment: Have you tried adding this to you outer most `<g>`: `<g transform="scale(.5)">`?

Comment: there also seem to be a difference between inline svg and ___ svg (not sure what's the alternative, block svg?)  -- and making it responsive may depend on that... again, I haven't been successful to make it responsive turning it display: inline, or display: block

No I haven't tried g transform="scale(.5)"... I'll try that now and reply.  thanks.

Comment: @zgood whoa.  Thank you.  That works.  But how do I make it responsive to the browser width?  Since the diagram will be generated by user and I cannot predict how small and large it would be.

Comment: Yes that is a bit more challenging... gimme a sec to work it out

Comment: Why does the entire image disappear when I try to put in percentage for the width/height?

Comment: Maybe because the SVG spec does not allow for % (which seems very odd to me) for the overall width and height of an SVG node. See [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-viewport-view-box.html#viewport) (look at the "Coordinate System Units" section)

Comment: Very odd indeed.  so forget the percentage.  Let's say I want to fix width to 1000px , and have the content regenerate to scale to it.  What do I do?  Currently, if I only change the width to 1000px, it'd crop out everything outside of 1000.  I assume I need to play with the viewbox and viewport?  I haven't tried the viewport, but I tried the viewbox -- and adding it would cause my image to disappear as well... which I also don't know why.  Edit: nvm.  The viewport is the default svg width/height set.

Comment: Off the top of my head the only thing I can think of is using javascript. You would have to divide the SVG width by the browser window width then set that as your scale number on your outer most `<g>`. i.e. if SVG width is 3840px and browser window is 2000px then - 2000 / 3840 = 0.5208333333333333, then `<g transform="scale(0.5208333333333333)">`. But I know there must be an easier way

Comment: @zgood  The javascript will definitely be my last resort.  I'm still searching for that "easier" way.  I'll let you know if I succeed.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll see if I can find anything

Comment: The lack of support for the SVG to have % dimensions actually seems smart now that I think about it. SVG is suppose to be "standalone" and "portable", and you can only use % if you have a parent container. If you have a parent container then you are no longer standalone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Contrary to the assumptions in the comments it is perfectly fine to use length values specified as percentages. The spec covers the [details](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#DataTypeLength) in its basic data types section.

Combining this knowledge with the hints  from the article you linked to in your question you could end up with something like the following for a responsive layout:

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 3840 7000" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
```

Comment: Yes, but it is not setting the width and height of the document.  It is only telling the renderer what the dimensions of the SVG contents are so that it can calculate the correct scale to use.  Assuming you know what the size of your SVG document is, then this is the simplest approach.

Comment: OK.  I realize I do know.  Although the svg will be generated by the user, the svg tag actually does specify the height and widht, however, at the format of <svg width="....px" height="....px">.  So I have to run some jquery to get it to format to viewbox="0 0 ... ...", which is easy enough to do.  Thanks for both your answers! I greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: @Novina The question is not, if you know the *external* size of your svg but rather the size of its contents. Since you placed the contents using coordinates, it's likely you will know these *internal* dimensions of your svg. The `viewBox` attribute is used to establish the *internal* coordinate system which is referenced by the contents, whereas `width` and `height` refer to the *external* coordinate system. The magic of responsiveness comes to play when the renderer scales the internal coordinates to fit the external ones respecting `preserveAspectRatio`.

Comment: Thank you.  It makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: But when I tried this code, it forces the svg to resize responsively to the height as well... which isn't what I want.  I switch it to xMinyMax, and it didn't do anything.  So how would I make it responsive ONLY to the width and have the height auto using this method?

Comment: @Novina To have the svg be responsive to the changes of width alone, you need to set `height` to a fixed value.

Comment: @Novina There is an excellent introduction to [svg coordinate systems](http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/) by Sara Soueidan. It's very comprehensive but definitely worth reading. She set up an [interactive demo](http://sarasoueidan.com/demos/interactive-svg-coordinate-system/index.html) as well, which is fine to play around with various values.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find anything native to SVG that could help you (I tried messing around with `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio`, but didn't have much success). I am sure there must be a way but I might be over looking something. If anyone has a better solution by all means post it!

I did get a JavaScript approach working so I thought I'd share it. In this demo I will use jQuery, but all of this could be done with vanilla JavaScript if you cannot use jQuery.

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    scaleSVG();
});

function scaleSVG(){
    var window_width = $(window).width(),
        $svg = $('svg'),
        ratio = window_width / $svg.width();

    $svg.css('min-width', window_width);
    $('g:first-child', $svg).attr('transform', 'scale(' + ratio + ')');
};
```

I have made a fiddle demoing this approach [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nx1q2bjk/) (it may take a second to load because of the size of the SVG).

You could probably also attached this `scaleSVG()` function to the window resize event like this:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).on('resize', scaleSVG);
});
```

I wasn't able to get this to work in the fiddle, but I'm thinking its because of the fiddle environment maybe???

Comment: Thanks for your effort.  I actually managed to get it to work without javascript last night using absolute position and a container.  One of the site I read suggested that, but I couldn't get it to work the first time -- probably because I didn't quite understnad the viewBox at the time.  This is a much simpler solution https://jsfiddle.net/  
However, I still don't quite understand how this would work.  I understand how absolute position works very well, but I didn't think absolute positioning actually do sizing as well...

Comment: @Novina Yes if you can avoid using javascript then that would be best ;)