# how to make the positions of lines in svg responsive

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive-design, position

I have a text and an image side by side with a little margin in the middle. I want to draw an arrow to a specific point on the image.

So for this I trying to use `svg` however, the position of the line is somehow not responsive. After reading a couple of questions here (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30717551/how-to-make-svg-responsive)) and blog posts (like [this](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/)) I changed all the values to `%` and also added the  `viewBox` attribute But for some reason the arrow is only in the correct position with my current browser screen 1920x1200. If I resize the browser window the arrow is at an incorrect position. My code:

html:

```
<div id="a">
This is the nose
</div><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 2000 2000" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <line x1="9%" y1="9.5%" x2="23%" y2="6%" marker-end="url(#triangle)" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.2%"/>
  
</svg>
<img src="http://www.hickerphoto.com/images/200/little-polar-bear_29287.jpg" />
```

css:

```
#a{
position: absolute;
margin-top: 8%;

}
svg{
  position: absolute;
  z-index:2;
  
}
img{
  margin-left: 20%;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o2fphns4/1/)

Anyone an idea why this is not working?

Is svg the even the right attempt here or should I use something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [SVG viewBox](https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/)
>   [Making SVGs Responsive with CSS - Tympanus](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/08/19/making-svgs-responsive-with-css/)
>   [SVG `text` and Small, Scalable, Accessible Typographic Designs](https://css-tricks.com/svg-text-typographic-designs/)
>   [SVG image element](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/image-element.html)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 2000 2000" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <image x="20" y="20" width="132" height="200" xlink:href="http://www.hickerphoto.com/images/200/little-polar-bear_29287.jpg" />
    <text x="25" y="55" font-family="'Lucida Grande', sans-serif" font-size="32">This is the nose </text>
    <line x1="9%" y1="9.5%" x2="23%" y2="6%" marker-end="url(#triangle)" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.2%"/> 
</svg>
```

Comment: so this means it only works when I "draw" everything in SVG ? There is no other way ?

Comment: I think it is the easiest way. Draw everything in adobe illustrator, Then export as `SVG` file. I made some of the SVG project using this workflow, i.e. Urban landscape in polygonal style : http://codepen.io/smalinux/pen/yJwJjm/left/. My SVG Workflow :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=06atTvwkuJE

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution, not sure if this is a good one, please correct me.

First of all I removed the `viewBox` attribute. Then I made the image also responsive by giving it a relative width and `height: auto;`. Lastly I also made the font-size responsive in the css through:

```
body{
 font-size: 12pt;
}
a{
 font-size: 1.5vh; 
}
```

Works when I resize the browser. Here the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o2fphns4/4/) . Please correct me if I'm wrong.