# svg line coordinates (x2,y2) is not working when changing the screen resolution in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, svg

> The coordinate value of x2,y2 getting from Database and x1,y1 is getting from Mouseoverevent using getBoundingClientRect().

> x,y value of line element is working fine but x2,y2 is not working when changing the screen size.

> x2(186) is coming from database, what i am doing currently is set the x2 value of 186/3.
> But the problem is when i am changing the screen size then manually change as 186/1.5 like that.
> x1-186 and y1-548 value stored in database.

```js
let svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];

$('table tr').hover(function(event) {

  let bound = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
  let style = getComputedStyle(svg);

  let paddingLeft = parseFloat(style['padding-left'].replace('px', ''));
  let paddingTop = parseFloat(style['padding-top'].replace('px', ''));

  let x = event.clientX - bound.left - svg.clientLeft - paddingLeft;
  let y = event.clientY - bound.top - svg.clientTop - paddingTop;

  if (event.x === undefined) {
    x -= parseFloat(style['border-left-width'].replace('px', ''));
    y -= parseFloat(style['border-top-width'].replace('px', ''));
  }

  let width = svg.width.baseVal.value;
  let height = svg.height.baseVal.value;


  if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= width || y >= height) {
    return;
  }

  console.log(x, y);


  var str = event.currentTarget.cells[2].innerHTML;
  str = str.substr(1, 18);
  var val = str.split(",");

  var x2 = val[0];
  (186)
  var y2 = val[1];
  (548)
  insertLine(x, y, x2 / 3, y2 / 3);
});

function insertLine(posX, posY, x2, y2) {

  let line = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'line');

  line.setAttributeNS(null, 'x1', posX);
  line.setAttributeNS(null, 'x2', x2);
  line.setAttributeNS(null, 'y1', posY);
  line.setAttributeNS(null, 'y2', y2);
  line.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', 'rgb(255,0,0)');
  line.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-width', 1);

  $(line).attr("id", "line");
  $(line).attr("marker-end", 'url(#arrow)');

  $("line").remove();
  svg.appendChild(line);
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at this: [Click event coordinates in SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54799299/click-event-coordinates-in-svg) Especially take a look at the `function oMousePosSVG()`. You may want to use this function to get the x and y in your code

Comment: Thanks for replay enxaneta. But my problem is when i increase the screen size more than 150% , Line element is not increasing size over certain width.This is my scenario [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39544480/5681336)

Comment: insertLine does not use y2