# D3js responsive svg width but not height

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, responsive-design

I have an svg bar chart I created in D3.js that I would like to be responsive horizontally but not vertically. Meaning I would like the size of the graph to decrease by width when the screen decreases in size, but never by height. I created a little example in a jsfiddle that is able to reproduce what I am trying to solve: [SVG changes width, but also height](https://jsfiddle.net/andrewsolis/0gfyoskc/) I've also attached the code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>svg responsive test chart</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <style>

    div.svg-container {
        height : 400px;
    }

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" > </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row svg-container">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <svg></svg>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <svg></svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var margin   = { top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10 },
        width    =  $('div.svg-container').width() - margin.left - margin.right,
        height   =  $('div.svg-container').height() - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    d3.selectAll('div.svg-container svg')
      .attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' +  ( width + margin.left + margin.right ) + ' ' + ( height  + margin.top + margin.bottom ) )
      .attr('height', '400px')
      .attr('width', '100%')
      .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMidYMid meet')
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
      .append('rect')
      .attr('x', 0 )
      .attr('y', 0 )
      .attr( 'width', width   )
      .attr( 'height', height )
      .attr( 'fill', 'purple' );


</script>
```

I figure it is probably something to do with `preserveAspectRatio`, where it is keeping the aspect ratio and therefore forcing it to scale down. However, I would like to instead just collapse the width and not the height. I've also followed this previous post [how to make svg responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30717551/how-to-make-svg-responsive), where it states to make the height hard coded, and set the width to 100%, but the graph still collapses both ways.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'none') ?

Comment: I did but it looks like the rectangles were still being scaled both along the x and y axis.

Comment: I tried here : https://jsfiddle.net/fh5kxv3k/  and it seems to scale only on x axis.

Comment: Ah yes, looks like for some reason the `width: 100%` for the svg itself was missing, which is why it wasn't doing it correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help you :)