# Make svg responsive on mobile monitor

Tags: html, svg, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make an svg with 4 ellipses inside, which overlap. It works fine but it doesn't seem to respond well when the size of the screen becomes to small. What should I do to make it responsive?

This is my current snippet for the svg elements:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <svg height="220" width="100%">
          <defs>
            <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
              <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);
              stop-opacity:0" />
              <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,255);stop-opacity:1" />
            </radialGradient>
          </defs>
          <ellipse cx="125" cy="110" rx="95" ry="85" fill="url(#grad1)" />

          <defs>
            <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
              <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);
              stop-opacity:0" />
              <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,255);stop-opacity:1" />
            </radialGradient>
          </defs>
          <ellipse cx="300" cy="110" rx="95" ry="85" fill="url(#grad1)" />


          <defs>
            <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
              <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);
              stop-opacity:0" />
              <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,255);stop-opacity:1" />
            </radialGradient>
          </defs>
          <ellipse cx="475" cy="110" rx="95" ry="85" fill="url(#grad1)" />


          <defs>
            <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
              <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);
              stop-opacity:0" />
              <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,255);stop-opacity:1" />
            </radialGradient>
          </defs>
          <ellipse cx="650" cy="110" rx="95" ry="85" fill="url(#grad1)" />

      </div>
    </div>
```

This is how it looks on normal monitor
[image]

and this on mobile screen:

[image]

Comment: You're missing the closing svg tag. But that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You can find hint from this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940741/making-svg-responsive

Comment: Yes indeed. The viewport is the way to go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making SVG responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940741/making-svg-responsive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the SVG to scale to the size of its parent container, then you need to tell the browser how big the SVG contents are, so it knows how much it needs to scale the SVG to fit the space available.

The way you do that is with the `viewBox` attribute.  The `viewBox` value consists of four numbers:

```
<left X> <top Y> <width> <height>
```

Your four ellipses occupy the area from 30,25 (top left of first ellipse) to 745,195 (bottom right of last ellipse).  So you should set the `viewBox` to:

```
 viewBox="30 25 715 170"
```

When you do that, the SVG will scale.

```html
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
      
        <svg height="220" width="100%" viewBox="30 25 715 170">
          <defs>
            <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
              <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);
              stop-opacity:0" />
              <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,255);stop-opacity:1" />
            </radialGradient>
          </defs>
          <ellipse cx="125" cy="110" rx="95" ry="85" fill="url(#grad1)" />

          <defs>
            <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
              <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);
              stop-opacity:0" />
              <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,255);stop-opacity:1" />
            </radialGradient>
          </defs>
          <ellipse cx="300" cy="110" rx="95" ry="85" fill="url(#grad1)" />


          <defs>
            <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
              <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);
              stop-opacity:0" />
              <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,255);stop-opacity:1" />
            </radialGradient>
          </defs>
          <ellipse cx="475" cy="110" rx="95" ry="85" fill="url(#grad1)" />


          <defs>
            <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
              <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);
              stop-opacity:0" />
              <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,255);stop-opacity:1" />
            </radialGradient>
          </defs>
          <ellipse cx="650" cy="110" rx="95" ry="85" fill="url(#grad1)" />

         </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
```