# How to create curve and circle in css and html5?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to the css world and I'm trying to make a responsive design like this using bootstrap, css and html5

for more information here is an illustration:

[image]

[curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vWVQ.png)
how to create the same curve and a circle above? i really need help i try everything but it doesn't work
a little help will be really good

Comment: SVG is what you actually want.

Comment: i think in html css it's good

Comment: Yeah, sure, good luck with that.  You could spend all day hacking something up that isn't going to work all that well, or you could shove 2 lines of SVG in your document.  Your choice.

Comment: for the svg we will always have a responsive problem while with hml css you can manage the responsiveness

Comment: That's simply not true.  SVGs can be ridiculously responsive.

Comment: yes ridiculously

Answer (score 2):

You have two options, the better is to use [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG) (I would go for this one if its me), also you can implement something like you provided in HTML but not every shape is possible to have using HTML, if curve and circles all you need then, something like can be implemented:

```css
.main {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  padding: 50px;
  position:absolute;
  top:-240px;
}

.inner {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: white;
}

.innerWhite {
  border: 1px solid 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="innerWhite"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for the svg we will always have a responsive problem while with hml css you can manage the responsiveness

Comment: I saw your answer there is just the curve because on your code instead of the curve there is a circle

Comment: SVG can easily mad responsive by just using [viewBox attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940741/making-svg-responsive).

Comment: where I have the most problem is at the level of the curve but not at the level of the circle https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vWVQ.png

Comment: @mathieu459, my answer is just to demonstrate how to create something similar to what you want, think can be fixed by making circles divs width bigger, and using translate CSS attribute, but need trail and error until you have it same as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use radial-gradient combined with mask:

```css
.box {
  height:300px;
  max-width:1024px;
  margin:auto;
  border:1px solid red;
  position:relative;
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:radial-gradient(circle 1800px at 50% -840px,transparent 53.8%,red 54% 60.8%,transparent 61%);
  -webkit-mask:radial-gradient(circle at 20% 70%, transparent 80px,#fff 81px);
          mask:radial-gradient(circle at 20% 70%, transparent 80px,#fff 81px);
}


body {
  background:url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/1000/800/800.jpg) center/cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><div>
```