# Absolute positioned element height exceeds parent on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an element with a background image that contains an absolute positioned element at the bottom.

When the screen width gets narrower, the absolutely positioned element height gets increased and exceeds the parent element. As known that position absolute elements get out of the flow, so the parent height is not changed.

```js
$(window).ready(function() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 767) {
    var heig = $('.overlay').height(),
      parent = $('.parent');
    parent.css('height', heig + 300 + 'px');
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/1000);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.overlay {
  background: #376c8d;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  border-radius: 160px 160px 0 0;
  font-size: 24px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="overlay">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing eli</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <a href="/">Link</a>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing eli</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <a href="/">Link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there is a way to keep the `.overlay` at the bottom, but all content is shown? Is there is a similar solution with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Constrain the proportion by making one property or another relative to the other.

```
background-size: 100% auto;
```

Edit:

[Use responsive SVG as the .overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940741/making-svg-responsive/25941018#25941018) to avoid layout reflow. Or output the content as an image if that suits your workflow or comfort level.

Comment: Did you test it and it worked? It's not working for me

Comment: No. When the .parent width changes, it affects the .overlay, which re-flows to accommodate the inner HTML. If you want to specify a height, then do so, but either 1) the content will reflow or 2) it will scroll. Or use JavaScript to adjust the font-size. Your initial statement was worded in a way which lead me to believe the background-image had anything to do with the problem... i.e. it was stretching because you set 100% 100% size and the content div was overlapping it with specific positioning.

Comment: If you make a minimally reproduce example it will demonstrate the problem. It sounds like you want a scalable  SVG or a responsive image.

Comment: The image is not the issue. I can set it to a color background, And it would stay the same. The issue is with the `.overlay` it's not showing with all the content, It's cut off from top

Comment: Right. From my experience this question arises from content that overflows a background-image with a specific region devoted to the aforementioned content. As opposed to creating structured, responsive HTML/CSS they place it very specifically and it does not scale well... With that said, using responsive SVG for the overlay should solve the issue.